# Prevent access through ip address

Tags: node.js, express

Using express.js how do I prevent requests from accessing my server through the ip address instead of through the domain fronted by cloudflare?

This is to prevent googlebot from indexing http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/

Comment: What are you trying to do, an ip blacklist?

Comment: You must use firewall to allow only from cloudfront ip.

Comment: @Mikkel explained the purpose a bit.

Comment: @EliasSoares Using ufw is the best way? I'd rather do a redirect from express.

Comment: Are you using EC2 for hosting? Use security groups instead. If not, use ufw also works. Theres a official list of cloudfront IPs in aws website

Comment: @EliasSoares it's cloudflare not cloudfront.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up with, hope it works.

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.host === '129.8d.xx.xxx') {
    res.redirect(301, 'https://example.com' + req.path)
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
})
```

Comment: Cloud flare also have the ip ranges: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/ you can use it to block requests that aren't from this ip ranges

Comment: Also I really suggest using the firewall instead of a application level blocking.